# How can you share script members between control template and item template

Tags: 2013, javascript, display-template

I'm developing two custom display templates (Control and Item template) and I'm wondering if it is possible to share script members between these two templates, e.g. if I add something like `var bar = 'bar';` in Control_MyTemplate.html can I reference it in Item_MyTemplate.html with `var fooBar = 'foo' + bar;`? Or do I need to extend the ResultScriptWebPart and add the property on the dataprovider? So far I tried adding the variable in a `<script>` container and in one of the scriptblocks with no luck.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sure you can.

It's JS code after all and you could either use a global variable to store your information or the provided ctx object.

Here' a example for both possibilities:

ControlTemplate:

```
    <!--#_
    window.ThisIsGlobal =  "this works !";
    ctx.MyVar = "THIS WORKS !";
    _#-->
```

ItemTemplate:

```
    <!--#_
    alert(window.ThisIsGlobal);
    alert(ctx.MyVar);
     _#-->
```

Comment: ah...I forgot to attach the member to the ctx object. Now it works like a charm, thanks!